# AngularJS: Unable to format null or undefined value with ngModelController $formatters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I have an AngularJS directive which contains a text input which has it's own model that gets passed a value from the controller scope through the directive's ng-model.

Check out this pen (& code below): http://codepen.io/ericwshea/pen/KwXRyr

The problem is that sometimes that model happens to be a null or undefined value, in which case I would like to use the text input's ngModelController to format the display of the null value in the text input to be something like 'NULL'.

It works if the value is some arbitrary string that I match in the formatter, but not if the value is null (I have also tested with undefined, same results).

Any insight/workaround on this, or is this just a shortcoming of $formatters?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" class="container">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl" class="col-md-12">
    <form>
      <input-directive ng-model="model"></input-directive>
      <input-directive ng-model="model2"></input-directive>
      <div ng-if="model">Model 1: {{model}}</div>
      <div ng-if="model2">Model 2: {{model2}}</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = null;
    $scope.model2 = 'make this null';
  })

  .directive('inputDirective', function() {
    var template = 
        '<div>'+
          '<div class="input-group">'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="localModel">'+
            '<span class="input-group-btn">'+
              '<button ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Save</button>'+
            '</span>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    function link (scope, elem, attr) {
      var inputModelCtrl = elem.find('input').controller('ngModel');

      function formatter(val) {
        if (val === 'make this null') {
          return scope.nullValue;
        }
        if (val === null) {
          return scope.nullValue;
        }
        return val;
      }

      scope.nullValue = 'NULL';
      scope.localModel = scope.ngModel;
      scope.save = function() {
        scope.ngModel = scope.localModel;
      }
      inputModelCtrl.$formatters.push(formatter);
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E', 
      replace: true,
      require: 'ngModel',
      template: template,
      link: link,
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      }
    }
  })
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a workaround for this. I initialize the value when the directive is created by placing a watch on ngModel, catching the null and making it 'NULL', which angular $formatters will actually format. I format the localModel's view value to the , and it works.

To make sure that the model value is correct when I send 'NULL' back from the directive to the controller scope, I use a $parser on the ngModelController to watch for the 'NULL' and convert it to null.

To bring it full circle, the $watch inside the directive on ngModel makes it so that if the value is set to null outside of the directive, the localModel gets re-initialized to 'NULL' and formatted for proper display.

This may seem ridiculous, but the actual real-world directive is a custom select menu which, as you could imagine, requires this functionality.

You can see the changes here: http://codepen.io/ericwshea/pen/KwXRyr

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = null;
    $scope.getModel = function() {
      return $scope.model === null ? 'null' : $scope.model;
    }
    $scope.setToNull = function() {
      $scope.model = null;
    }
  })

  .directive('inputDirective', function() {
    var template = 
        '<div>'+
          '<div class="input-group">'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="localModel">'+
            '<span class="input-group-btn">'+
              '<button ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Save</button>'+
            '</span>'+
          '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    function link (scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      var inputModelCtrl = elem.find('input').controller('ngModel');
      var nullDisplay = '<NULL>';

      function ngModelParser(val) {
        if (val === 'NULL') return null;
        return val;
      }

      function localModelFormatter(val) {
        if (val === 'NULL') return nullDisplay;
        return val;
      }

      scope.save = function() {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(scope.localModel);
        console.log(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue);
      }

      scope.$watch('ngModel', function(val) {
        if (val === null) val = 'NULL';
        scope.localModel = val;
      })

      inputModelCtrl.$formatters.push(localModelFormatter);
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(ngModelParser);
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E', 
      replace: true,
      require: 'ngModel',
      template: template,
      link: link,
      scope: {
        ngModel: '='
      }
    }
  })
;
```

I hope this helps anyone that runs into a similar issue, even though this scenario is rather specific (specific enough that I had to answer it myself!)